# Needed: easy program for inserting symbols and Unicode characters

Tags: macos, keyboard, software-recommendation, text-input

On MacOS 10.11 I am constantly going to the Emoji & Symbol viewer to bring in arrows and other kinds of symbols:

[image]

Problems with this interface include:

- It it bound to the current program, rather than operating system level. So you need to make the window appear for each application you use.
- It doesn't allow searching by Unichar
- It doesn't let you see the entire character set

I'm looking for a program that keeps my favorite symbols all in one place in a floating window and lets me easily insert them into the current application. Does such a program exist?

Comment: @TomGewecke Open for business now... :[)

Comment: I believe it does in fact allow searching by unicode characters. Try typing the hexadecimal number into the search bar.

Comment: And you can see the entire character set—just enable the “Unicode” category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UnicodeChecker

[image: app screenshot]

[UnicodeChecker](http://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/index.html) is an excellent app showing each of the possible Unicode characters. Search the more than 110,000 characters by name with a press of Command+F. Frequently updated to keep up with changes in the [Unicode standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Use the `Favorites` menu to quickly access your frequently-used characters.

[image: favorites screenshot]

Comment: Even better! It's free!

Answer (score 1):

[Ultra Character Map](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ultra-character-map/id520265986?mt=12) should do what you want: